# Cocoapods Replace the Email

Tags: cocoapods

I use `pod trunk register XXXXX@mail.com` register an account, but I want to change the email, how should I do.

Cocoapods 1.2.1 
Xcode 8.3.2

how to Logout? how to Login?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such feature of changing an email. But you can do something like this-

From your old email account (the owner account), make the new email as owner-

```sh
pod trunk add-owner FooPod new@example.com
```

Now, from your new email account (which is also the owner now), remove the old email as owner-

```sh
pod trunk remove-owner FooPod old@example.com
```